# How can I stop an application from being installed to all models?

Tags: android

We have a requirement to publish a free application in the Android Market. As the company paying for the application is a handset manufacturer they only want the application to be allowed to be installed on their devices. I.e. not visible or installable from Android devices made by other manufacturers.

It must also be possible to supply free updates to the application.

Answer (score 1):

A "hack-ish" solution:
Use "" market filter and point it to some internal(manufacturer specific) shared library.
Out of curiosity, why would you have manufacturer specific app in market? Would it not ship with phone and be updated via OTA?

Comment: It is a manufacturer specific app because they are the ones paying the bill. This fits their requirements. On some devices it will be preloaded. Older devices will have the ability to download. It seems like the market place would be a good place to start. The phone has the ability to check for updates built-in. We could reinvent the wheel and do it ourselves but why when something close may fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

Google announced the ability to prevent certain devices from being able to view your app on the Android Market today. You can do this from the Android Market Dashboard page for your app.

Comment: Thanks - will check the announcement.

Comment: Wooow! That's right, on my app it says available on 331 devices and it seems that you can exclude some of them! It's a brand new feature in the market developer console. Well done Wesley :)

Comment: Interesting that it coincides with the Netflix app being released.

Comment: It is a shame that you can only exclude (opt out) rather than only include (opt in). In our case we want to support only certain models. This list will have to be constantly monitored for when a new model appears and then exclude or am I missing something?

Comment: @user586539 That is my understanding as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify which models an app can be installed on. But your app could refuse to run if installed on a device made by this manufacturer, by checking the [Build.MANUFACTURER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER) value, and saying "Sorry, this app only runs on FooBar devices". (By the way, that makes a little advertising).

Note that this may results in bad ratings and angry comments on the market such as "doesn't run on device X".

Also, ask all possible values of Build.MANUFACTURER to your company/customer. It isn't always the same for a given manufacturer.

By the way, if your app is popular then this protection is likely to get cracked. You will need to obfuscate your code and add some other weird and inventive security tricks/checks. For this purpose, you may ask the manufacturer and/or look for some specific/hidden files which are only present on their devices, etc...

Comment: Thanks - we do use obfuscation (ProGuard). If I downloaded a application and it didn't run on my phone I'd probably give a bad review. We want to prevent someone downloading only to find it doesn't work.